# $initdb /usr/local/var/postgres #initdb: command not found

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to initiate db by using `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres` but all I get in return is `initdb: command not found`. Is there any step(s) I may have missed after installing Postgresql that is causing this?

*EDIT*
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, I want to use it for Ruby on Rails and I was told to the this:

Initiate db `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`

Initiate server:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Edit example.database.yml;

Create project db: `rake db:create:all|production`

Start Redis e Sidekiq

brew install redis

- Mac -

  redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
- Debian -

  redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf

--

```
bundle exec unicorn -D -p 3000 -E production -c config/unicorn.rb
```

Comment: What OS is that? Most linux distros provided their own facility to initialize the db.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Let me guess: [debian](https://serverfault.com/questions/773215/postgresql-installation-under-debian) or derivatives?

Comment: Did you install with the distro's package manager? If so, it should have initialized the db automatically.